# How to set Navigation bar for three.js panorama

Tags: three.js

I am Learning three js and I have 2 Questions for far.

1. How Can I Set Navigation bar for panorama like "Zoom",Horizontal and vertical Rotation...
2. How Can I restrict zoom control "Camera zoom" like below Example which is done in below link. Currently in below link when we scroll up it reverse the camera(I want to restrict that)

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

For 2nd point i have search in stackoverflow and found that we can achieve same by setting FOV but it is not working.

Can anyone give me example with above link please...